# Why is animation (transition) not applied the first time the property is set

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a simple setup with a box moving using `left` property to the right. The property is updated by a button click. Why is transition animation not applied the first time I click on the button?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');
  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const current = parseInt(box.style.left);
    box.style.left = (isNaN(current) ? 0 : current) + 50 + "px";
  });
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of `left` is `auto` and `auto` is not a transitionable value.

You would need to explicitly set `left: 0` to have a transition then.

Comment: great, thanks, `auto` is not a  transitionable value for any property, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Start with some initial value for `left`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const current = parseInt(box.style.left);
        box.style.left = (isNaN(current) ? 0 : current) + 50 + "px";
    });
})
```

```css
.box {
            left: 0;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: green;
            position: relative;
            transition: left 1s;
        }
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As "left" property is intialized as "auto", no transitions can be applied.
Instead try this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const current = parseInt(box.style.left);
        box.style.left = (isNaN(current) ? 0 : current) + 50 + "px";
    });
})
```

```css
.box {
   left: 0;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: green;
   position: relative;
   transition: left 1s;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```